# Map from Bruhat stratification to Catalan stratification for the space of totally nonnegative upper-triangular matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, total-positivity

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$This question came up in a class ["Total Positivity and Cluster Algebras" being taught by Chris Fraser](https://sites.google.com/site/cmfraser37/teaching/8680).

Let $N^+$ denote the space of uni-upper-triangular matrices in $\SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, and $N^+_{\geq 0} \subseteq \SL_{\geq 0}(n,\mathbb{R})$ the totally nonnegative parts of these spaces.

There are two stratifications of $N^+_{\geq 0}$ that I want to compare.

The first is what I'll call the **Catalan stratification**. It's the stratification based on the location of nonzero entries for a matrix $M \in N^+_{\geq 0}$, which can easily be seen to necessarily lie below/to the left of a Dyck path. E.g., one stratum in the case $n=5$ is:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & * & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & * & * & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & * & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & * \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
where the $*$'s denote the nonzero entries. So there are $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ many strata here, and the closure relation among these strata is just containment of Dyck paths.

The second is more sophisticated; I'll call it the **Bruhat stratification**. For $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, let $x_i(t)$ denote the matrix with $1$'s along the main diagonal, $t$ in the $i$th spot right above the main diagonal, and $0$'s elsewhere. It's a theorem of Lusztig that for any permutation $w \in S_n$ and any reduced word $(i_1,i_2,\dotsc,i_\ell)$ of $w$, the map $(t_1,\dotsc,t_\ell)\to x_{i_1}(t_1)\dotsb x_{i_\ell}(t_\ell)$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{\ell}$ onto $Y^o_w := B^{-1}wB^{-1} \cap N^+_{\geq 0}$, where $B^-$ are the lower-triangular matrices in $\SL(n,\mathbb{R})$. (See [Hersh - Regular cell complexes in total positivity](https://arxiv.org/azbs/0711.1348) for background on this.) So we have a stratification of $N^+_{\geq 0}$ indexed by permutations in $S_n$, and the closure relations among these strata is the (strong) Bruhat order on these permutations.

**Question**: Is it true that every Catalan stratum is a union of Bruhat strata? If so, what's the resulting map from permutations to Dyck paths?

I suspect the map from permutations to Dyck paths might be something like the "Cambrian congruences" of Nathan Reading. But I also suspect that this question may have already been studied somewhere.

Comment: Though with the Cambrian congruences you get the Tamari lattice, whereas the Dyck path order is a different thing: it's a distributive lattice. So now I'm not so sure...

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the Bruhat strata, but I don't see how for instance the Catalan stratum with just a single star in the top right corner can contain any Bruhat stratum.

Comment: @lambda: sorry, I got the pattern of zero/nonzeros exactly backwards for the Catalan strata! It is corrected now. Thanks for spotting this error!

Comment: Indeed, now that I think about it a matrix of the form I was thinking about clearly isn't TNN.

Comment: Have you tried finding your map using http://www.findstat.org/MapFinder?Domain=Cc0001&Codomain=Cc0005 ?

Comment: @ChristianStump: okay, I wrote some Sage code (https://cocalc.com/share/363023871ecc3c464c7e3400be3b647ccf5eba8d/bruhat_catalan_stratification.sagews?viewer=share), and with this was able to generate data for $n=4$, which FindStat said must be the map (http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00127/) which sends a permutation to its Dyck path of left-to-right maxima.

Comment: @SamHopkins congratulations!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Catalan strata are unions of Bruhat strata, and the resulting map from permutations to Dyck paths is indeed given by taking the left-to-right maxima.

There is a way to parametrize totally nonnegative matrices by writing them as Lindström-Gessel-Viennot matrices for a certain weighted directed graph. This is explained nicely in the first section of ["Total positivity: tests and parametrizations"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9912128), by Fomin and Zelevinsky, where the directed graph is depicted in figure 2. They explain the parametrization for general matrices, but if you want to restrict to uni-upper-triangular ones then simply keep just the part of the graph with blue edges.

This combinatorial picture is then refined to also parametrize $Y^o_w$. They construct a directed graph for every reduced word $(i_1,\dots,i_{\ell})$. See figures 4 and 5, where for your case you only have blue edges.

Now, for every permutation $w$ you have a canonical reduced word of the form
$$(m_1,m_1+1,\dots,n_1)(m_2,m_2+1,\dots n_2)\cdots (m_k,m_k+1\dots n_k)$$
where $n\geq n_1>n_2>\cdots >n_k\geq 1$ and $n_i\geq m_i\geq 1$, which is just the first reduced word for $w$ in the reverse lex order. By drawing the associated directed graph we can find out exactly which matrix entries will be nonzero! The $ij$ entry is nonzero if and only if there is a way to travel from source $i$ to sink $j$. This already means that each $Y^o_w$ sits inside a unique Catalan stratum, and therefore each Catalan stratum is a union of Bruhat strata.

In order to get the description of the map from permutations to Dyck paths there are probably many ways to see it. I reasoned as follows: a pair $(m_i,n_i)$ from above is "redundant" if there is some other pair $(m_j,n_j)$ with $n_j>n_i$ and $m_j\le m_i$. Removing all the redundant blocks from the reduced word can be seen not to affect which matrix entries are nonzero, therefore it stays within the same Catalan stratum. This produces a 321 avoiding permutation which has the same convex hull as $w$ from the upper right corner (See corollary 5.8 in ["Some Combinatorial Aspects of Reduced Words
in Finite Coxeter Groups"](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1997-349-04/S0002-9947-97-01805-9/)). Incidentally, this 321 permutation also represents the lowest dimensional Bruhat cell in the Catalan stratum.

Comment: Terrific! I guess the one further question I might have is whether this LRM map plays nicely with the two partial orders (Bruhat order and the distributive lattice of Dyck paths)- e.g. is it a lattice congruence? But that's a purely combinatorial question, I suppose, independent of the geometry.

Comment: @SamHopkins:  Looking at the $S_3$ example on the findstat link given above, we can see that the map is not a lattice homomorphism.  There is no lattice congruence on the weak order on $S_3$ that has 4 singleton congruence classes and a class $\{312,321\}$.

Comment: @NathanReading: thanks! (I guess the other natural remaining question is if this can be extended to other types, but of course that would belong in another MO question.)

Comment: @SamHopkins:  For that question, I would start with the Stembridge reference that Gjergji Zaimi gave.